# Finding standard deviation in c++ with file

Tags: c++

Write a program that takes its input from a file of numbers of type double. The program outputs to the screen the standard deviation of the numbers in the file. The file contains nothing but numbers of type double separated by blanks and/or line breaks. The standard deviation of a list of numbers x1, x2, x3, and so forth is defined as the square root of:

((x1 – a)2 + (x2 – a)2 + (x3 – a)2 + ...) / (n - 1)

Where the number a is the average of the numbers x1, x2, x3, and so forth and the number n is the count of how many numbers there are.

Your program should take file name as input from the user.

I have already created a file in the computer. When I finish the code and try to compiled it, it cannot open the file in the compiler. I don't know what is the problem going on. Can anyone give me some advices?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double next, avg,var,stdDev, sum=0, sumSq=0;
    int count=0;

    cout << "Enter filename:" << endl;
    std::string filename;
    cin >> filename;

    ifstream in_stream;

in_stream.open(filename.c_str());


   while(in_stream >> next)
   {
       sum+=next;
       sumSq+=(next*next);
       ++count;       
   }

   avg=sum/count;
   var=(count*sumSq-sum*sum) / (count*(count-1));
   stdDev=sqrt(var);

   in_stream.close();

cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(3);
cout << "The standard deviation is " << stdDev << endl;



return 0;
}



 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luJZx.png



 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofZGR.png


 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTFSL.png
```

Comment: Where is the file located?  Where is the .exe located?

Comment: Are you sure that the file resides in your programs working directory?

Comment: Also fix your question title please! It's obviously completely unrelated to your actual problem. Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please, and leave out all that irrelevant stuff.

Comment: It cannot open the file ? How do you know that. The posted code makes no effort to check *any* of your IO operations. And you may want to read this to see why [`while(! file.eof() )` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). If you indeed cannot open the file, my crystal ball tells me its because the *working* directory your process is running from is not the same as that where `nums.txt` resides.

Comment: Also asking for entering a filename and actually don't put a statement doing this looks pretty silly for me. I don't know who upvoted this poor question for what ever reason??

Comment: There is so much wrong with what you've done. Be systematic. Try tracing through your code with a debugger and you'll find many deficiencies.

Comment: @ NathanOliver: my file is located on the Desktop. What do you mean by .exe? I think the file name should be .txt.

Comment: Your program does not allow the user to input a file name. Instead, it hard codes this file name as nums.txt in both getAverage() and standardDeviation(). To allow the user to input the file name add `std::string fileName; std::cin >> fileName;` after the first line in `main()`, after the line with `std::cout ...`, and add `#include <string>`. Then, pass `fileName` to both `getAverage()` and `standardDeviation()` and use them to open the file (i.e., `file.open(fileName.c_str())`). Note that is this just a start. There are still so much that is bad/inefficient with your code.

Comment: @aichao: I try to rewrite my code. But I stop after the average part, because I am not sure how to write the standard Deviation part.

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: the key is to sum the square of `next` while summing `next` as `sum`. Call that `sumSq`. Then the unbiased sample variance is `(count*sumSq - sum*sum)/(count*(count - 1))`. The unbiased sample standard deviation is just the square root of that. BTW, your posted code still has problems. One of which is that you are missing a `)`.

Comment: @aichao: Is it sumSq=sqrt(sum+next)? for the standard deviation part, do I need another while statement like the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double next, avg, var, stdDev, sum=0, sumSq=0;
  int count=0;

  cout << "Enter filename: ";
  std::string filename;
  cin >> filename;

  ifstream in_stream;
  in_stream.open(filename.c_str());
  if(in_stream.fail()) {
    cout << "Could not open the file " << endl;
    exit(0);
  }

  while(in_stream >> next) {
    sum += next;
    // sum the square of "next"
    sumSq += (next * next);
    ++count;
  }

  avg = sum/count;
  var = (count*sumSq - sum*sum)/(count*(count - 1));
  stdDev = sqrt(var);

  cout << "The mean is: " << avg << endl;
  cout << "The unbiased sample variance is: " << var << endl;
  cout << "The unbiased sample standard deviation is: " << stdDev << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compile this and execute the executable from the **SAME** directory as your `nums.txt` file. Then after the program prompts you with `Enter filename:`, enter `nums.txt`. For example, a screen grab of my session in a terminal is:

[image]

I used `g++` but you can use `clang++` as well to compile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This one helps me a lot. After I rewrite my code, when I input the filename, the output is "The standard deviation is nan." Not a specific number, actually I put some numbers into my file.  Do you know what is the problem of this?

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: can you post the input file? How many white-space separated numbers are in the file?

Comment: I don't know how to insert a file. Can I post it like an image?

Comment: You can. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: make sure your input file contains only numbers (can have decimal and sign) that can be converted to double. Otherwise, you will get `nan`. I did not get a `nan` with the data in your screen grab.

Comment: My input file just have numbers (no decimal and sign). May be there are some errors on my code. Can you take a look for my code?

Comment: You need to change your posted code in the question to be the code in the answer. Your posted code in the question will not even compile correctly. If you do that and follow the commands in the session screen grab that I just posted, then all will be well.

Comment: I have already updated my code. This one is the complete code.

Comment: Compiling using `clang++ -o std_dev std_dev2.cpp` and running your posted code, I get `The standard deviation is 33.982` as the output for your `nums.txt` file. So, there is nothing wrong with your code now. Like I said, if mums.txt has any non-numeric lines in it, then you will get `nan`.

Comment: I double checked my code and my file. There is no error in the code also no numeric lines in the file, but I just keep getting "nan" when I compile the program.

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: take a look at my session screen grab that I just updated. When you `cat` your nums.txt file, do you get the same output as that shown in the screen grab?

Comment: No. I post an image during my compiling.

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: please issue the command `cat nums.txt` in the terminal and show me the screen output.

Comment: I tried as you said, but I get the same result. I also post the image.

Comment: Ok! I know what is the problem because I do not put the file in the right path.

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: the `cat nums.txt` command should be run from the terminal prompt and **not** as the input to your program. Just run `cat nums.txt` from the terminal and post that screen shot. Don't run `./a.out`.

Comment: @ZiWeiPan: Yes, you should check to see if the stream opened correctly. You had that before and you removed that from your code! See the code posted in the answer. You are getting `nan` in this case because `count` is zero.